# A number of duplicates posted in the last hour by different users

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Either someone is creating a bunch of accounts and asking very similar questions, or a bunch of people from the same math class all decided to use SO to do their homework. A search for [mcnuggets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mcnuggets) is a good example; can a moderator check to make sure this isn't the same person over and over again?

**EDIT**:

This guy is out of control. In the last ten minutes, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051141/diphontine-equations-closed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051189/diphontine-equations). Maybe he should be banned?

Comment: He's at it again... I can't imagine that that many different people in one class would have exactly the same idea to post pretty much the exact same question (unless it's a "how to abuse SO" class). It seems like one person to me, just repeatedly creating accounts to get around any bans that may be in place.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

OK, I deleted all these duplicates. How convenient for us they all used unique words; "Diophantine" is also good.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050882/diophantine-equation-closed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050475/solving-diophantine-equations-using-python
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046564/problem-solving-in-python-program-closed

I guess we can thank their teacher for that courtesy!

Edit: wow, this is a much more serious problem than I realized. I count DOZENS (literally, dozens!) of accounts spamming us with the same bad python assignment questions. Two IP ranges, both map to Universities in India.

Laying down wide IP bans:

```
# incredibly abusive indian university homework, dozens of accounts
# spamming the same gratuituous homework questions
-A INPUT -s 210.212.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 218.248.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

(specifically 218.248.5.222 and 210.212.222.90)

Also destroying many, many accounts.

Comment: My lecturers have recommended me to tell my friends about Stack Overflow... I'm having second thoughts after what just happened.

Comment: He's still at it (I edited the question to include a couple new links). EDIT: Oh, [that was fast](http://stackoverflow.com/users/367951/jagadeesh) :)

Comment: @Bolt - so you prefer having lots of questions/answers about the same problem (duplicates) instead of having only one thread to look for? Duplicates are noisy and confusing, why should they not be closed?

Comment: @Carlos I think he means he doesn't trust classmates not to abuse it like this if he tells them about it -- he was one of the people telling the spammer to knock it off

Comment: @Bolt, @Michael - ups, sorry, i got it the other way.