# I am unable to access Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ban

Hey there,
Frm the past few days, I am unable to access the site. I access the Internet via a 3G connection and my ISP has given me a shared IP address (218.248.84.95). I am on a Mac.

Problem: when I try to open `stackoverflow.com`, it just keeps on connecting, and after some time it finally gives the error "The connection has timed out."

Temporary solution: I am using a proxy server to access the site, which is highly inconvenient, as my trial will expire in the next three days.

My firewall is off and I am on a Mac. I use internet tethering via an iPhone, and I am unable to access the site directly on my iPhone. The only temporary solution, for now, is the proxy server.

Comment: Wow. Someone's earned a Dedicated badge.

Comment: Since you said you use a shared IP, my first guess is that you're using the same IP as someone who has been banned. It's just a guess, though; I'm not a team member.

Comment: if the case was about being banned, i guess the site would have atleast opened and displayed some message informing i am banned, i dont think it is the problem.

Comment: @Ibrahim For IP-based bans I don't think it does; based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/a-number-of-duplicates-posted-in-the-last-hour-by-different-users/53807#53807) it looks like they just tell iptables drop all packets from that IP

Comment: @Michael: More importantly, Ibrahim's IP falls into the 218.248.0.0/16 block Jeff banned there.

Comment: @RBemrose :D Wow; I didn't even notice. You should post it as an answer

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your IP is currently blocked on StackOverflow's routers/firewalls, as noted in [A number of duplicates posted in the last hour by different users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/a-number-of-duplicates-posted-in-the-last-hour-by-different-users/53807#53807).

(Marked as Community Wiki, because Michael Mrozek linked to that post initially.)

Comment: Note: I assumed routers because iptables is a Linux command, and SO's web servers run IIS.

Comment: Good catch. That ban was ages ago, so they're probably willing to revoke it now (and you're probably right about the router/firewall part, they [run Linux](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/SO_NY_Diagram.jpg))

Comment: Why would the OP have been blocked only recently then?

Comment: @Michael Myers: Because it's a shared IP... meaning that, from time to time, his IP changes.

Comment: Ah, yes, didn't catch that.