# Are these the same users (future sock puppets?)?

Tags: support, sock-puppets

- User [Maosud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533875/maosud) joined 2 days ago and asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378361/placing-content-over-an-iframe/4379568) about placing a div over an iframe "from Photosynth.net".
- A few hours later [Rashid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528532/rashid) (who joined 7 days ago) asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381219/how-to-add-a-div-above-the-iframe/4381334#4381334) about putting a div over an iframe, showing the source of the iframe as being from photosynth.net
- 1 hour later user [ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/532804/ahmed) (who joined 3 days ago) posted [this "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381219/how-to-add-a-div-above-the-iframe/4381913#4381913) to that question; summarized: *"thanks all for reply and sorry for miss understanding [...] wiating the answer and thanks"*.

Similar questions, English usage, rep, joining time frame, and ethnic usernames is not much to go on. As a non-moderator can I see IP addresses? Is there anything that should be done about these possible duplicate accounts?

Comment: I think you're wrong on this one (see my answer) but +1 for vigilance.

Comment: +1 for vigilance, too. Unrelated: I think the people who do the sock puppet thing may need to find better hobbies, as that particular one sure seems to be a lot of work for so little return!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are these the same users?

Maybe, maybe not. **Having more than one account is allowed** as long as you don't upvote yourself.

Given that none of those accounts have cast a single vote, this is not the case here. So leave it be.

Comment: Ahh; interesting bit of detail there, and that makes sense... especially given that probably the quickest/easiest way to identify dupes (same source IP at the same time) could easily be explained by multiple people behind NAT.

Comment: Related MSO post: [What are the rules governing multiple accounts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/11107541)

Answer (score 3):

Because of the activity tabs of their profiles, I don't think these users are sockpuppets. They could just be on the same team. Or, there might be no real affiliation with Photosynth; it could be a [homework assignment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/a-number-of-duplicates-posted-in-the-last-hour-by-different-users/53807#53807) or example of some kind that uses `photosynth.net` that as an example URL.