# Sock puppet edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, sock-puppets

I just rejected [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2845209) from a user that seemed to be a sock puppet... although both accounts have 1 rep and were created 4 days apart, it just felt awkward to see the two user names involved.

That said, I would have rejected it anyway, just thought I'd slip a word about that user here; so far it doesn't seem to be doing anything bad, but the pieces are in place:

[image: Master of Puppets]

The suggested edit might have been "accidental", but if it had been approved, that would have been an illicit +2 already... but I don't know if there's another puppet at play (these two haven't actually *done* anything except posting 1 answer each; the suggested edit seems to be the first "cross-puppet" interaction), so I'd think the best thing to do is just to report it here?

Comment: Just saw this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71700/are-these-the-same-users-future-sock-puppets?rq=1 - "let it be" I guess?

Comment: Well, those users are now merged into one. Well done! ;)

Comment: With identical gravitars and names they may be unintentional socks (or did that situation not obtain earlier?). A comment pointing the user at the help center page about account management (and merging in particular) might be in order.

Comment: They were JohnDoe and DoeJohn; you're seeing the post-merge result :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's the problem? A poor edit should be rejected regardless of whether it was a sock puppet or a 200K user - so you did the right thing.

Having a sock puppet is also okay provided it isn't used to prop up another account. It's likely that this particular instance isn't a sock puppet, it's probably just a user who lost his login info from the first time he registered so he made another account (they should be merged).

BTW that's a great album you illustrated - arguably Metallica's best work.

Comment: Haha indeed! I think I hear "Master! Master!" every time I read "sock puppet" on MSO :)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it contains more information... although 200K users don't *suggest* edits... :)

Answer (score 4):

These accounts pretty obviously belong to the same person. And they're possibly trying to quietly inject links to a particular website into posts.

I'm going to merge them for now and then we'll see how it goes.

Comment: Haven't clicked the link that was suggested, but the URL seemed legit though. Fair enough!

Comment: @retailcoder It may or may not be legit, but in combination with only tangentially-relevant answers and no disclosure, it looks a lot like blind promotion.