# Odd watij questions

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, new-users, abuse

I noticed that suddenly several users with very simple names (e.g. "joe") and score=1 ask the same question about running `watij` (whatever that is). These questions are all very similarly (poorly) written so I'm wondering if it's the same person asking over and over. The last one is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607972/working-with-eclipse-and-watij). I've seen one other similar question that I don't have the link now.

Yesterday, I marked two made by the same user with 50 min of difference ([this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603626/how-to-run-watij), as a dupe of [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603419/get-watij-to-run)). So, I'm wondering if one of the Omniscient-And-All-Powerful-Mods here can check if it's indeed the same guy?

Comment: ["**Watij** (*pronounced wattage*) stands for Web Application Testing in Java. Watij is a Java API created to allow for the automation of web applications."](http://watij.com/)  While it doesn't seem unreasonable to get *some* questions about such a thing, it does seem very unreasonable to get so many low-quality dupes about it suddenly.

Comment: @Charles that's sounds actually something I may be interested in learning actually :)

Comment: Might be a whole class posting their homework, like [earlier for "diophantine"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/a-number-of-duplicates-posted-in-the-last-hour-by-different-users/53807#53807), @Charles.

Comment: @Arjan, I'm also reminded of the rash of hotel reservation system questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to flag such users with a mod flag whenever you see this.

That's the easiest and simplest way -- and if you can provide a link to the other user in the mod comment that'd be awesome!

Comment: OK. I'll do that. I just don't want to over use the flags also, hence this question here.