# This guy keeps changing profiles to crowd-source his project

Tags: discussion, abuse, multiple-accounts, crowdsourcing

The title pretty much sums it up. I could find at least 8 questions and 3 profiles just today.

Is this abuse? Should I do something about it? *What* can I do about it?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694007/it-should-display-a-number-which-is-the-number-of-buttons-selected-but-it-is-not
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692595/incorrect-number-is-displayed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692424/it-displays-a-string-where-it-shouldnt-do
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692371/alert-appears-at-the-wrong-time
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691670/wrong-number-is-displayed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691448/wrong-number-is-shown-in-textbox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690037/incorrect-number-is-displayed-in-the-textbox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445119/my-grid-is-not-appearing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716760/jquery-displaying-text-or-textbox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709077/jquery-code-needs-a-bit-of-fixing
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719769/jquery-application
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720923/how-to-use-this-closest-in-this-situation
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737357/some-buttons-are-displayed-or-not-displayed-when-they-shouldnt-be
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799973/it-displas-the-wrong-value-in-the-textbox
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826576/its-not-displaying-these-buttons-straight-away-when-rows-are-added

**UPDATE**

It seems as if the moderator's hard work eventually paid off! He is now harassing [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/M_6371222.html)!

Comment: Err which guy, exactly?

Comment: Well... that's the thing... he keeps switching profiles. The jQuery grid guy.

Comment: Who? When? Why? Every user account has a user ID; you could post at least that.

Comment: [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1122133/user1122133) I think, already suspended. I flagged one of [this person's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1117111/user1117111)'s posts indicating it was probably a ban bypass attempt by the same user

Comment: Those questions are awful and need immediate burnination.

Comment: Not sure about that last link in the question though.

Comment: @Mat, you're right... there's nothing wrong with that question. I just wanted to provide proof of multiple profiles.

Comment: We noticed this a couple of hours ago, we're working on it.

Comment: His questions are way too localized. I doubt I'd find anyone else who'd benefit from his questions (honestly, loaded the wrong library?).

Comment: Anna just vaporized a few more attempts today. He'll get sick of it, eventually. There's twelve of us and one of him.

Comment: @Tim, that doesn't seem to [bother him too much](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8699688/464709), though. Maybe some kind of harsher warning is in order?

Comment: That does indeed look a lot like [this guy's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1122133/user1122133) style & fiddles (which are pretty much identical to [this other guy's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1054876/malcolm-pickup))

Comment: I think it's cool to have a site with users and mods who are willing to take the time to keep it useful for everyone, especially with persistent annoyances like this. Just thought I'd say that :)

Comment: Wow; persistent little bugger, isn't he!

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716760/jquery-displaying-text-or-textbox) is claiming to be the bugger's classmate. Still got nuked (10k only).

Comment: @Michael - that last one claims his professor told their students to come to SO for help!!!

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I find it unlikely that several different people in the same class are posting about the same problem using an identical post format and content that contains only minor variations that don't fundamentally change the question (and sometimes no variations at all). Not impossible, but certainly improbable.

Comment: @Anna, I tend to agree.  I certaintly wasn't criticizing the deletion - I flagged the post, as a matter of fact.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I didn't take it as criticism. Just figured I'd add my thoughts to the discussion. :)

Comment: [Here's another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719769) to add to the list. (10K only)

Comment: And another: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8720923/102937

Comment: @Anna Lear: [Not impossible indeed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53806/a-number-of-duplicates-posted-in-the-last-hour-by-different-users)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on this user.  We'll keep an eye on him at EE and if he violates any of our policies we'll send him back to you :)

Comment: Now that's what I call hyphenated justice!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799533/textbox-isnt-displayed-when-it-should-be

Comment: This little bugger is persistent.  Isn't this project due by now?

Comment: Yep, _theyyyyyyyyy'rrrrrre back!_ Now if we can just get Carol Ann to stay _away_ from the light this time. Seriously, sometimes Stack Overflow is like a bug light for those that care about nothing else but themselves.

Comment: Merged two more accounts this morning.

Comment: Another sock: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8955736

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Update**

It turns out there wasn't just one bugger... there were *a few* buggers from a certain educational institution behind this madness, along with some *honest* classmates who were *very willing* to tell on them :)

We've dealt with the real issue now, so we won't be seeing these guys again for a while.

**Stack Overflow - 1

Cheaters - 0**

---

Yeah, it looks like someone doesn't appreciate suspensions as New Year's presents. He should be glad we're giving him anything after he ostensibly wound up on Santa's naughty list.

> Is this abuse?

Of course. Creating new accounts to evade suspensions is an outright no-no on almost any online community, not just Stack Exchange.

> Should I do something about it? *What* can I do about it?

Raise us a flag. <del>Bitches</del> Mods love flags.

In all seriousness: things like this should be brought to mod attention ASAP, even though there are probably enough of us to go around. The generous character limit you get for raising flags means if you can help us find substantial evidence and point us to it via links, as you have done here on meta, it makes things much easier for us, so don't feel like you're completely powerless when it comes to problem users.

Definitely feel free to close the reposted questions if they are blatant reposts or blatant crap (which most of them are). Just remember: there is only so much the community can do.

Comment: +1 for "Bitches loves flags"

Comment: Oh man. Now you've made me *so* curious which educational institution that was.

Comment: (Was it the Bedlam School for Young Offenders?)

Comment: @Pekka: The *what*?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn How come we get _minus one_ and they only get _minus zero_?!

Comment: @Bolt http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bethlem_Royal_Hospital

Comment: I know - it's the 2013 course of a University whose curriculum concentrates entirely on Spamming

Comment: @Pekka웃 University of Huddersfield

Answer (score 45):

This is obvious, and blatant abuse. It's being dealt with. This particular account does not care about the rules, our community or anything else that doesn't deliver a gift wrapped lump of code, despite accepting several answers.

So now it's a short lived game of Space Invaders, as the individual(s) keep creating new accounts. Not all twelve hands are present at the time of this writing (it is a holiday), but the hands that are present are *really* pissed. We'll make it stop.

**Update**

This seems to have died down, at least for now (I wasn't greeted with even more upon checking the flag queue today).

Note, moderators do not have the ability to ban an IP address, that is a dev only ability. Additionally, IP bans are ugly. My ISP (for instance) routes a huge internal range (/20, sometimes /16) through a single public IP. Hence, a single ban would cut off quite a few people.

While adding them is at the sole discretion of Stack Exchange, I don't like them unless circumstances are extreme. While annoying, I don't think this particular case was really *extreme*.

**Update II**

There's been talk in comments about *hellbanning*, or basically putting a user obliviously into their own little bubble. In this case, the user was making a different account with a different OpenID each time. For any kind of ban to work, it would need to be done at the IP level. I really feel restrictions based on IP alone are ugly.

As long as the community remains extremely efficient at spotting and reporting this type of behavior, we don't have to do stuff like that or even uglier things like browser fingerprinting. To be clear, *you* did most of the work here by alerting us to more incidents within minutes of them being posted. Sure, it takes a few moments to run some checks and then ultimately launch missiles but I'm quite happy to do that if it avoids the alternatives.

This was a good demonstration of just how effective the site's immune system is. We've got lots of healthy white blood cells and a dozen antibodies on hand just in case.

Comment: On the contrary, I'm actually enjoying this a fair bit, but maybe only because I'm a rookie.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Or maybe you just like Space Invaders.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: Who doesn't?

Comment: Galaga > Space Invaders

Comment: We regular users appreciate the time you mods spend dealing with nonsense like this.

Comment: I'm with @Bolt. I've found (and flagged) six of this guy's accounts so far. It's a fun way to pass time during builds.

Comment: Just vaporized another one. I _almost_ admire the persistence ... _almost_.

Comment: Soooo, why can't you guys just IP-ban him and be done with it?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing that @bob just asked.  Does DHCP make it hard for your all to IP ban people?

Comment: @BobCratchit Moderators can't IP-ban people directly. It's a dev-only thing. We haven't ruled an IP ban out, but we're trying other approaches first. Once a ban is in place, we're not gonna lift it and if the questions are posted from a public place we may be locking out legitimate users as well.

Comment: @AnnaLear Very good points.

Comment: @Anna and Tim, I remember reading a blog post from Jeff about silently banning users.  Having it look like they were regular users doing their thing, but nothing they post is ever visible to anyone.  Basically they're posting junk in their own little bubble.  Was that ever implemented on SO?  Seems like it would be *perfect* for this guy.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: ["hellbanning"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/suspension-ban-or-hellban.html), which I doubt has been implemented (yet).

Comment: @Bolt - that's it!  Thanks.  Should definitely be implemented—Mods' time is too valuable to spend on silliness like this...though hopefully this guy is gone now?

Comment: @Adam Rackis: Can't say for sure yet. We're still monitoring.

Comment: *"On the contrary, I'm actually enjoying this a fair bit, but maybe only because I'm a rookie."* ... @BoltClock'saUnicorn, you're freaking awesome. :)

Comment: @AdamRackis I updated my answer. A hell ban really isn't effective against someone that keeps creating new and unique accounts unless implemented at the IP level. And even then, it's just too easy to use a proxy. Any action taken on the IP level is ugly unless there's a way for legitimate users sharing that IP to not be affected.

Comment: @Tim - I can't imagine IP banning to **ever** be effective/possible, between coffee shops and DHCP, but this isn't my area of expertise.  I brought up hellbanning because I figured it would *obviate* the need for IP banning.  I would think the hellbanned user would be sitting in his private bubble figuring that people got tired of his crap and are ignoring him.  I would think anyone smart enough to surmise that they had been hellbanned would be smart enough to figure out JQGrid :)  But it looks like he's on the "hyphenated site", so this is likely, (hopefully) all moot.

Comment: Eventually, this individual will realize that there's _twelve_ of us and _one_ of him (or her). This is starting to become annoying.

Comment: Hellbanning will work if the jerk doesn't create a new account.  If it does that, detection will be difficult due to the ban.

Answer (score 19):

I've seen this user before and have dealt with some of his accounts. As Tim and Boltclock said, we're working on these ones as well.

This is annoying and abusive, but nothing we can't put a stop to with a bit of work. :)

Comment: Heh, when he gives up on SO and starts posting it here instead, does it mean we won?

Comment: So...he's posting the same question over and over and over?  How odd.

Comment: @Adam Rackis: He's posting the same set of fiddles, but either repeating the same questions or asking questions that differ just tangentially. Basically he's getting us to put something together for him, piece by piece.

Answer (score 12):

Search google for the jsfiddle

**Hottest 'dom' Answers - Stack Overflow**
stackoverflow.com/tags/dom/hot?filter=day
I've updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/11/ function numberKeyUp(input) { // I added this to deal with empty values. ...

**incorrect number is displayed - CodingForums.com**
www.codingforums.com › ... › JavaScript frameworks
1 post - 1 author - Last post: 3 Jan
... above what needs to happen so that the number 4 is displayed except for the number 6? code is in jsfiddle click http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/21/ ...

**incorrect number is displayed - WebDeveloper.com**
www.webdeveloper.com › ... › Client-Side Development › JavaScript
2 posts - 2 authors - Last post: 2 Jan
... above what needs to happen so that the number 4 is displayed except for the number 6? code is in jsfiddle click http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/21/ ...

**... above what needs to happen so that the number 4 is displayed except for the number 6? code is in jsfiddle click http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/21/ ...
ultra media: SitePoint Forums**
ultraamedia.blogspot.com/2012/01/sitepoint-forums_2056.html
2 Jan 2012 – code is in jsfiddle click http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/21/ ... I have a slight situation in my jsfiddle which I believe can be explained easily ...

**incorrect number is displayed | Flip Forum**
flipforum.org/incorrect-number-is-displayed/
... example above what needs to happen so that the number 4 is displayed except for the number 6? code is in jsfiddle click http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/21/ ...

Textbox is displaying NaN [closed]
programmersgoodies.com/352379/textbox-is-displaying-nan-closed/
31 Dec 2011 – I've updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/11/ function numberKeyUp(input) { // I added this to deal with empty values. ...

**textbox is displaying NaN - CCQQ.net**
textbox-is-displaying-nan.8690899.ccqq.net/
I've updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC/11/ function numberKeyUp(input) { // I added this to deal with empty values. ...

Comment: Just as an aside: SE allows for searching URLs too, like: [url:"http://jsfiddle.net/uXZcC*"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FuXZcC*%22). That finds one more to delete ;-)

Comment: My point was the number of other sites the same fiddle occurred

Comment: This is beyond crazy. He's harassing the whole Internet.

Comment: lol @Pekka Harassing the whole internet! All the time/effort he's spending, seems like he could learn some of it himself.

Comment: @Pekka You've got to be mildly impressed, though.  We may be witnessing the birth of a whole new spamming technique.

Comment: @JCL yeah. Crowdsourcing at its finest (see the update to the accepted answer).