# "Free hosting" questions are both awful and ubiquitous

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, low-quality-posts

Searching for "free hosting" on Stack Overflow yields [5000+ mostly awful one- or two-sentence *unclosed* questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=free+hosting+closed%3A0&submit=search) soliciting advice for free/cheap hosting. Disregarding the very low quality of most of the questions, they seem to be the kind of shopping question that is currently highly discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Is this worth some kind of mass vote-to-close movement, like the [mass burnination of the homework tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag)?

Comment: The search terms as listed is basically `free OR hosting`, which is going to be very inaccurate.  [`+free +hosting`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bfree+%2Bhosting+closed%3A0&submit=search) "only" has 840ish questions.

Comment: I completely removed the few [free-hosting] questions (or a very similar tag) the other day...

Comment: Actually this may be slightly over-stated, the further you go into the search results the less related to "free hosting" the questions become. There are still quite a few pages of mostly garbage though.

Comment: @Charles, Er, yes. This.

Comment: Yes; what you said! Such questions are also a significant attractor of hosting spam.

Answer (score 7):

I think you'll do better if you either limit to words in the title:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Afree+title%3Ahosting+closed%3A0

Or make *sure* both words appear in the post by adding a `+` to the search terms

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bfree+%2Bhosting+closed%3A0

I don't think it's quite as dire as you're making out, though **both lists are worth a look by diamond mods**. I removed a few egregiously poor examples, but it wasn't like dozens or hundreds of things that clearly needed mass removal.