# Why is problem sets not available as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Problem sets as a concept is widely used in academics. There is also a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_set) entry to moot. Will someone add this as a legal tag for use across some of the Stackexchange sites?

Comment: Why would you need a 'problem-sets' tag on Pets.StackExchange.com?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - they need `problem-pets`.

Comment: @Oded: No thanks, I have plenty of those at home..

Comment: Fair enough, the tag is required in *some* of the sites.

Comment: After all the work to [get rid of the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated), this is the last thing we need on SO.

Comment: @lifebalance: Which ones do you have in mind (not that I'm in agreement with this)?

Comment: SO and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, what's with this down voting of -8? Isn't that a bit harsh for such a legitimate question? Or is there another meta-meta site that I should be posting this?

Comment: @lifebalance: [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta): it can be used to express agreement or disagreement with a feature request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag on StackOverflow, but it was [officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) and then removed in a long cleanup process. The [reasons for removing the homework tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) all remain true. To quote from that discussion:

> - homework is a meta-tag. It describes the status from which the question is being asked, not the content of the question.
> - homework might be factually incorrect - for example, it is possible to ask a basic question yet not be a student or otherwise completing
>     an assignment.
> - Copied assignments (verbatim) with no attempt at solving the problem are not real questions and should be closed anyway.
> - Someone, somewhere, will feel the need to say "is this homework? is it? is it homework? Really?" then somebody else will "USE THE HOMEWORK
>     TAG11!!11" (and I'm mildly fed up of it).

How would a [problem-sets](/questions/tagged/problem-sets) tag differ from the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag? Even if there were some distinction, people would be sure to use it the same way.

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147794/language-agnostic-programming-problem-sets) (which has been just removed!) is asking about how to go about finding or defining problem-sets as practice problems.

Comment: @lifebalance: That sounds like it might be off topic for Programmers. It would certainly be off topic for SO. It would likely be on topic for academia.stackexchange.com (which [does have a homework tag](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework)).

Comment: Fair enough. By the way, instead of removing that question, is there a process by which it can be "deported" to academia.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @lifebalance That's called migration: you can flag a post for migration by a moderator, though now that it's been deleted it's too late

Comment: I guess the question would have been off-limits to SO. But between Academia and Programmers, the question belongs in the latter. IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

Sure. Because our cooking site really needs it.

Or the lego site.

Or the pets site.

I think you are getting my drift here.

Tags are easy enough to add - you just create them if you have enough reputation - there is no need to add a default one that will not be relevant to most sites.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation on Stackoverflow.com - would you do the honours?

Comment: @lifebalance - what question would benefit from it? I don't necessarily think we _need_ another **conceptual** "meta" tag, not after trying to get rid of them.

Comment: If practice-problems exists, what's wrong with problem-sets?

Comment: @lifebalance - there is no such tag on [so]. And [programmers.se] only has 7 of those. Clear sign that it is not actually needed.

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/147794/46808) question has it.

Comment: @lifebalance - There are 7 such questions on programmers. 5 of which are closed. You linked to one of the two remaining questions.

Comment: Oops! So, they are going to get closed as well?

Comment: @lifebalance - don't know. Depends on the questions themselves and whether they _fit_ Programmers.