# Possible abuse -- two accounts for duplicate questions

Tags: support, abuse

So [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9739113/497356) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9743679/497356) questions are so similar (basically some find and replaces) that I voted to close the second one. In fact, it would appear the second user slipped up in a comment on the second question:

[image]

The data mentioned here is in the format the first question mentions, not the second one

Note, however, that the users are different. The accounts have existed for roughly the same period of time and are from at least the same country.

On the other hand, the questions the users have asked seem distinct until now.

I think it's pretty clear that the questions are at the very least duplicates, but if so it seems like there's some abuse going on here, especially since there are two users involved.

What's the right action to take here? Or am I just being paranoid?

Comment: Students, doing the same assignment?

Comment: Flag one of the posts and link to the other in the flag message. Moderators can investigate and take action if needed. (On another note, the whole "students taking the same class" thing seems to be happening a lot lately...)

Comment: @AnnaLear - Perhaps some teachers have become so lazy that they prefer to send their students to SO for help rather than teaching the material themselves. Provided some of the homework questions I've seen lately, I wouldn't doubt it.

Comment: The data is in the format mentioned in that question, `id:ID,value:VALUE`, the first question has format `VALUE:abbr`. I think you have a temporary paranoia attack ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's good to be paranoid about some things, but we'll take your worries and make them our burdens any day. It's literally what we live for. So, like I said in [another somewhat related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117611/this-guy-keeps-changing-profiles-to-crowd-source-his-project/117615#117615):

> Raise us a flag. <del>Bitches</del> Mods love flags.

But anyway, there is indeed a whiff of abuse going on here, and investigation is underway.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. I thought you lived for harassing users by closing/deleting their questions, especially the high-rep ones, but now it looks like you're picking on the newbies.